# How to get each value of unserialized data

Tags: php, serialization

Lets say I have this data...just an example!

```
    Before Serialize
        array (size=2)
          'first_name' => string 'Swashata'
          'last_name' => string 'Ghosh'
    After Serialize
   a:2:{s:10:"first_name";s:8:"Swashata";s:9:"last_name";s:5:"Ghosh";}
```

So after the serialized data I'm going to unserialized it and get each value of the element of array to make it variable. The problem here is I want to get each element to make them a variable so that I can easily call them when I need it. Thanks! ahead.

Comment: Please explain what your question is.

Comment: What I want here is to get the value of each element that stored in my array.

Comment: Do you simply mean `foreach($array)`?

Comment: You have serialize and unserialize functions in PHP.. 
If you want it in normal PHP array just unserialize it..

Comment: Heres the thing regarding on my example..                                    $array = array(
    'first_name' => 'Swashata',   <-- I want to get this value to make it variable..and how? I try using $array[0] but doesn't work.
    'last_name' => 'Ghosh',
);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ask for extraction of key => value to variables..

So ..

```
$array = array(
    'first_name' => 'Swashata'
    'last_name' => 'Ghosh'
);

extract($array);
```

This will create variables called $first_name and $last_name with their values from your array..

Answer (score 1):

After unserialize you need to call

```
$unserialized = unserialize($data);
echo $unserialized['last_name'];
```

not `$unserialized[0]`

You can use this as well

```
extract($unserialized);
echo $last_name;
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its in json format

Use `json_decode()` to get the values from serialized data

```
$a = "serialized data";
$arr = json_decode($a);
print_r($arr);// will get back the result
```

Comment: I don't understand where did you see json ?